# Chromatic Number and Average degree

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any relation between **average degree** of a graph and **chromatic number**?

Like if an average degree for a graph is 3.4. Can we say that the graph is not 2-colorable?
for Number of edges = 17 and vertices are 10.

So my question is can we do prove of this using handshaking lemma min.degree <= 2E/V <= max. degree ?
i.e. if my average degree comes say **x** then chromatic number is greater than or equal to x ?

Answer (score 6):

You can't do very much. Note that the complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ has average degree $n$ yet it is 2-colorable.

I think the "best" bound of this type that one could possibly obtain is by using the inequality $$\chi(G) \leq \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{2m+\frac{1}{4}},$$ holding for a graph with $m$ edges.

Comment: How about a lower bound for $\chi(G)$ in terms of average degree? OP is mentioning his interest in lower bound in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about $\text{Chromatic_Number}($G$) = X(G) ≤ 1 + \text{Average_Degree}(G)$,

I can’t think of a counterexample, but can’t prove it either

Comment: This isn't true: take $K_n$, add $\binom{n-1}{2}$ isolated vertices, and you have a graph with $\binom n2$ vertices total and $\binom n2$ edges. So the average degree is $2$, yet the chromatic number is $n$.

Comment: @ Misha Lavrov What if G is connected?